# jQuery not working properly in my website

Tags: jquery, html, css, gallery, carousel

Firstly, I will post the code here but it is way too big and I'm not sure which part of the code is causing this problem so if anyone request particular section of code, I'll post them up here.

I'm designing my website here and have implemented polaroid jQuery plugin (http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-polaroid-gallery-plugin) into  circular content carousel (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/),

Everything seemed to be working except, when I scroll to left, the whole polaroid gallery goes invisible. I'll explain in picture.

[image]

[image]

Anyone know what is causing this problem?
Again, if anyone requests, I'll post sections of code here as it is way too big.

Thanks

HTML Code:

```
<div id="ca-container" class="ca-container">
                <div class="ca-wrapper">
                    <div class="ca-item ca-item-1">
                    <div class="ca-item-main" style="background-color:#9C6;">           <div class="ca-icon"></div>

 <br>

                            <h3>blah blah</h3>
                            <h4>
                                <span class="ca-quote">&ldquo;</span>
                                <span style="margin-top:-30px;"> blah blah</span>
                            </h4>
                                <a href="#" class="ca-more">more...</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ca-content-wrapper" style="background-color:#9C6;"> <div class="ca-content">


        <div class="cata" data-name="blah" data-cataimage="images/IMG_4878.jpg">



            <div class="pg_photo" data-image="images/IMG_7806.jpg" data-title="blahblah" >




                 <div id="pg_des" align="left" style="display:none">
                    <span>
                         <b>blah</b>
                    </span>
                 </div>

            </div>

            <div class="pg_photo" data-image="images/IMG_7782.jpg" data-title="blah" >

                <div id="pg_des" align="left" style="display:none">
                    <span>
                         <b>blahblah</b>/span>
                 </div>

            </div></div></div></div></div>
```

EDIT:

These are the scripts that's been called out. It is placed in the bottom of the HTML code instead of calling it in the header.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.contentcarousel.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#ca-container').contentcarousel();
        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: how are u initialising content carousel?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. please have a look at the carousel code and see if you see any error? cheers

Comment: no no..show us how you've called content carousel on your HTML.. we need ur code..

Comment: edited again to post part of the html code that calls out carousel. thanks again.

Comment: js code .. where u call $("selector").contentcarousel()

Comment: remove the code carousel code and show us what **u** typed

Comment: the html code posted here is mostly my code as it is repeated except <div class="ca-item ca-item-1"> changes to <div class="ca-item ca-item-2"> and so on

Comment: also added in the javascript!

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate ids in your html.  Try changing `id="pg_des"` to another a unique id or a class.  Duplicate ids often cause strange behaviour like this!